# Use Java Reflection to find sum of parameters from list of objects

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, reflection

I have a list of Items...

```
public class Item implements Serializable {
   private Double subTotalCash;
   private Double subTotalCredit;
   private Double totalShipping;
   private Double grandTotal;

   private Integer countSubItems;
   private Integer countSomethingElse;
   private Integer countMoreThingsNotListedHere;

   ...
   // getters and setters here
}
```

All the parameters that matter are Double, Integer, Float, or Long (all extend Number)
What I want to do is to sum each of the parameters and total them up in one 'Master' Item.

```
Item masterItem = new Item();
for(Item item:items) {
   addValuesFromItemToMaster(item, master);
}
```

If it was only a dozen or so values It'd be no big deal, but we're talking about a bunch of parameters and they change frequently enough that I don't want to have to remember to update this code when the Item object changes....So my thought was that I'd use reflection to get all the fields that are assignable from Number and and sum them but how do I do the actual addition?

```
private void addValuesFromItemToMaster(Item child, Item master) throws Exception {
    if(child == null || master == null) return;

    Field[] objectFields = master.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : objectFields) {
        if (java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())) continue; // don't add any static fields
        if(!Number.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) continue;  // If this is not a numeric field
        if(field.getType() == AtomicInteger.class || field.getType() == AtomicLong.class || field.getType() == Byte.class || field.getType() == BigInteger.class) continue;

        Number childValue = (Number)PropertyUtils.getProperty(child, field.getName());
        Number masterValue = (Number)PropertyUtils.getProperty(master, field.getName());

        if(childValue == null) continue;
        if(masterValue == null) masterValue = childValue;

        // is there something I can put here to get the masterValue += childValue?
        // is there a way to cast to the field.getType()?

        BeanUtils.setProperty(master, field.getName(), n);
    }
}
```

Comment: If your design is such that you look at it and think, 'reflection would be better than dealing with this', maybe your design needs a rework.

Comment: @kasdega Why don't you use method. or you can extends and add method to count.

Comment: If you have numbered entries in your class, why don't you use a list instead? this way you wouldn't need to remember, how many items you have. I also don't realy understand your question. You have already the number fields, so why can't you sum them?

Comment: @Devolus not all fields are numbered, I changed my example code to reflect that.

Comment: @Patashu Java's reflection is a tool just like anything else in java....it has its place, it can be incredibly powerful, and/or horribly misused, or both.  Your blanket statement is misleading.  It implies that there is never a situation where reflection is a good answer, and that I must respectfully disagree with.  Reflection has its time and place and used appropriately can be an absolute God send.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// is there something I can put here to get the masterValue += childValue?
// is there a way to cast to the field.getType()?
// setMethod.invoke(master, newValueGoesHere);
```

Yes, there is:

```
if (field.getType() == Integer.TYPE || field.getType() == Integer.class) {
    Integer i = masterValue.intValue() + childValue.intValue();
    setMethod.invoke(master, i);
} else if (field.getType() == Long.TYPE || field.getType() == Long.class) {
    Long l = masterValue.longValue() + childValue.longValue();
    setMethod.invoke(master, l);
} else if (field.getType() == Float.TYPE || field.getType() == Float.class) {
    Float f = masterValue.floatValue() + childValue.floatValue();
    setMethod.invoke(master, f);
} else if (field.getType() == Double.TYPE || field.getType() == Double.class) {
    Double d = masterValue.doubleValue() + childValue.doubleValue();
    setMethod.invoke(master, d);
}
```

Comment: I figured out if I use apache's beanutils and propertyutils I can replace the getMethod and setMethod stuff I was doing with PropertyUtils.getProperty and BeanUtils.setProperty.  Then I can remove the repeating line setMethod.invoke with one BeanUtils.setProperty outside of the if/else's.  Thanks for your answer it got me going again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/api/index.html) rather than straight reflection API. With BeanUtils, ensure your class conform to JavaBean rule, and use `public static Map describe(Object bean)` to get a list of property available on given bean.

Once you get the name of properties, you can get inidividual value by using `public static String getProperty(Object bean, String name)` and sum it all up

Comment: After looking into this further I ended up doing something like this.